# Applying multiple PTransforms on one PCollection simultaneously in Apache Beam pipeline

Tags: python, apache-beam

I am trying to create a beam pipeline to apply multiple ParDo Transforms at the same time on one PCollection and collect and print all results in a list. So far I've experiencing Sequential process, Like first ParDo then second ParDo after that.
Here's an example I have prepared for my issue:

```
import apache_beam as beam

from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions())

class Tr1(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, number):
    number = number + 1
    yield number

class Tr2(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, number):
    number = number + 2
    yield number

def pipeline_test():

  numbers =  p | "Create" >> beam.Create([1])
  tr1 = numbers  | "Tr1" >> beam.ParDo(Tr1())
  tr2 = numbers  | "Tr2" >> beam.ParDo(Tr2())

  tr1 | "Print1" >> beam.Map(print)
  tr2 | "Print2" >> beam.Map(print) 

def main(argv):
  del argv

  pipeline_test()

  result = p.run()
  result.wait_until_finish()
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(main)
```

Comment: Can you attach the graph of the dataflow job where you see the PTransforms are running sequentially?

Comment: It's also unclear what your question / problem is.  Others are assuming you think it is a _problem_ that things are running sequentially instead of in parallel.  Is that true?  Also, as others asked, if you _see_ that the graph is parallel, but you _observe_ that things are running sequentially, that's just an implementation detail of the runner.  Eg, the `DirectRunner` will obviously not parallelize as well.

Answer (score 1):

The scheduling of transform and elements is managed by the runner used to run the pipeline.

Runners typically tries to optimize the graph and might run certain tasks in sequence or in parallel.

In your case, both Tr1 and Tr2 are stateless and are applied to same input. In this case, runner typically run them on the same machine in sequence for the **same element**.
Note, runner will still run different elements in parallel.

It should look some thing like this.

Thread 1
ele1 -> Tr1
     -> Tr2

Thread 2
ele1 -> Tr1
     -> Tr2

I would not recommend relying on the expected parallelism of different part of the pipeline as it depends upon the runner.